# Android - Convert json which has uncertain keys to map using kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, data-class

I have a json like this. I need to convert it to data class

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": "111",
        "type": "1",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Jack",
                "value": "26",
                "age": "0.0"
            },
            {
                "name": "Lisa",
                "value": "18",
                "age": "1.0"
            }
        ]
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "222",
        "type": "2",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Brown",
                "value": "23",
                "age": "30.0"
            },
            {
                "name": "Andy",
                "value": "18",
                "age": "23.0"
            }
        ]
    },
    "className": "A01"
}
```

I define the following data class

```
data class Orders (
    val className: String?,
    val classes: Map<String, EachClass>
)

data class EachClass (
    val id: String,
    val type: String,
    val items: List<Person>
)

data class Person (
    val name: String,
    val value: String,
    val age: String
)
```

And the result always show

> className=> A01, classes=> null

I searched the stackoverflow and they said using TypeToken. But I have a field called "className" which cannot be convert with EachClass object

```
val type = object : TypeToken<EachClass>() {}.type
val obj = Gson().fromJson(data, EachClass::class.java)
```

and I found TypeToken with HashMap<String, Object> is working but its ugly and I need to convert to data class myself.

I'm appreciate if someone can tell me the correct way to convert the json. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gson does not provide built-in functionality for this specific situation so you need to do some manual conversion, but luckily for your use case it is not that much work. The following approach should work:

1. Parse the JSON as Gson's [`JsonObject`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html)
2. Remove the `className` member and store it for later
3. Parse the `JsonObject` as `Map<String, EachClass>`
4. Construct an `Orders` instance from the results from step 2 and 3

The complete solution could look like this:

```kotlin
object OrdersDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<Orders> {
    private val classesType = object: TypeToken<Map<String, EachClass>>() {}.type

    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): Orders {
        val jsonObject = json.asJsonObject
        val className = jsonObject.remove("className").asJsonPrimitive.asString

        val classes: Map<String, EachClass> = context.deserialize(jsonObject, classesType)
        return Orders(className, classes)
    }
}
```

You would then register it like this:

```kotlin
val gson = GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Orders::class.java, OrdersDeserializer)
    .create()
```

Alternatively you could also convert it to a regular class and use Gson's [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) annotation on the `Orders` class to avoid having to register the deserializer manually.

Note: Normally is recommended to prefer `TypeAdapter` over `JsonSerializer` / `JsonDeserializer` to allow streaming the data for better performance. However, since you need to work on a `JsonObject` here anyway (therefore non-streaming) using `TypeAdapter` does not provide an advantage here and might only complicate the implementation a bit.